# Chrome Extension: Focus on my search input field when user open a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that overrides the default new tab. I have a search input field on this new tab page that I want to focus this field on when a user opens a new tab. I have seen many answers, but none of them is satisfactory since they all have some URLs on the address bar. This extension [Ocean Hero](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oceanhero-save-the-oceans/cdbccfkcpkmimlajcjpodelocoeifjhp?hl=en) has managed to achieve this neat and clean.
One thing I notice with this extension is when we open a new tab, initially, the focus is on the address bar then after a blink, it goes to the below searchfield.

**one more thing, When I am adding autoFocus to the field it is not visible in the browser elements attributes.